# How to concatenate all files with a certain extension in directory structure

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm trying to write a simple script for the windows command line that takes all files in the directory structure (files in the same folder as well as other folders in that directory), and concatenates them into a single file. In this case I only want to grab javascript (*.js) files.

This is what I have so far after viewing similar questions on this site.

```
@del pheonix.js
@FOR /R %%i in (*) do @type "%%i"\*.js >> pheonix.js
```

When I run it I get "The directory name is invalid." Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `*.js` in `for` loop and remove the `\*.js` from your `type` command.

Also I would recommend you to use different extension for the output file (at least temporarily) to avoid the `for` trying to append the file to itself.

```
@echo off
del pheonix.js
FOR /R %%i in (*.js) do type "%%i" >> pheonix.tmp
ren pheonix.tmp pheonix.js
```

Had you removed the `@`'s from your batch, you would easily see what's wrong yourself:

```
D:\temp>FOR /R %i in (*) do type "%i"\*.js  1>>pheonix.js

D:\temp>type "D:\temp\aaa.js"\*.js  1>>pheonix.js
The directory name is invalid.

D:\temp>type "D:\temp\bbbb.js"\*.js  1>>pheonix.js
The directory name is invalid.

D:\temp>type "D:\temp\subfolder\cccc.js"\*.js  1>>pheonix.js
The directory name is invalid.
```

Comment: If you want only `*.js` files, then use `FOR /R %i in (*.js)`. Otherwise this command will take each and every file.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Thanks. I haven't noticed. Updated the answer.